# Set user under a windows domain with no domain available

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain

I just bought a notebook for my company for a colleague to replace an old one.

I should set it up for as the user can login into our company domain as

```
MY_COMPANY\name.surname
```

The problem is I'm far from office and out of the domain.

What I cannot figure out is if I can setup the pc anyway so the user can log in with his domain credentials, whatever the domain is available or not, without being in my company where the domain is reachable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the domain via VPN, it is possible. Can you make a VPN connection?  In addition, the domain policy must be set to cache credentials.  In some cases you need to confogure the system to dial a VPN connection before logon.

You will need to conenct and join the domain as a user that is permitted to join a system to teh domain.  You will then need to log on as the user

If you cannot connect, it will be unlikley you can configure the new laptop.

Answer (score 1):

To join the domain your computer must communicate with the "Domain Controller" once it has done that once you will (if the administrator has enabled password caching) be able to log on to your laptop without being on the domain, but that first joining must be able to communicate with the DC.

Normally you would need to do in your situation is connect to a VPN and then join the domain. Ask the IT staff if they have a VPN you can connect with.

However *you still may not be able to join the domain*! only users with a special permission are allowed to join computers to the domain. You will need to ask your IT if you have domain joining permisisons, and if you don't you will need to have your IT department join the laptop for you.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy allows the configuration of credential caching.  Default value is for the last 10 logins to be cached.  Anything over 0 will allow login with the cached set of credentials.

Set under:
    Computer Configuration\Wuindows Setting\Local Policy\Security Options\Interactive Logon: Number of previous logons to cache